# Jquery plugin with multiple instances

Tags: jquery, plugins, multiple-instances

Hello I tried multiple solutions that I could find forums but, I think I need to understand the very basic first :)

I created a (very) simplified example of a plugin I want to create and it uses mouse events on different DOM objects, but now on click all divs change to 'lime'. How can I fix this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($, color, otherColor){
var otherColor= 'yellow';

$.fn.tester = function(color, otherColor){
    otherColor= otherColor;
    this.css('background-color', color);
    this.on('click', changeColor);
}

function changeColor(e){
    $(this).css('background-color', otherColor);
}

}(jQuery));
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tester').tester('green', 'purple');
    $('#tester2').tester('black', 'gray');
    $('#tester3').tester('orange', 'lime');
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="tester" class="row tester" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
    <div id="tester2" class="row tester" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
    <div id="tester3" class="row tester" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the color in a closure. If you use a global variable, it always contains the last color that was set.

```
this.on("click", function() {
    changeColor(this, otherColor);
});
```

...

```
function changeColor(element, color) {
    element.css('background-color', color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
(function ($, color, otherColor){

    $.fn.tester = function(color, otherColor){
        this.css('background-color', color);
        this.on('click', function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', otherColor);
        });
    }

}(jQuery));
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tester').tester('green', 'purple');
    $('#tester2').tester('black', 'gray');
    $('#tester3').tester('orange', 'lime');
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="tester" class="row tester" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
    <div id="tester2" class="row tester" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
    <div id="tester3" class="row tester" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```